# How can I parse url to get all data-id of embedded video present in this page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse this URL http://www.espncricinfo.com/ to get data-id element within article tag

My script:

```
import re
import pytz
import requests
import datetime
from flask import url_for
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
data_id = []

bigbash_article_link = "http://www.espncricinfo.com"

r = requests.get(bigbash_article_link)
bigbash_article_html = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(bigbash_article_html, "html.parser")


bigbash_items = soup.find("section",{"class": "contentCollection contentCollection--hero"})
print(bigbash_items)
```

I want to get all the data-id of embedded video link present on this page.

Expected output :

```
data_id = [22615485,22616496,22619773,...............]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
data_ids = [x['href'].split('=')[1] for x in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'icon-font-before icon-chain-solid-before', 'href': True})]
print(data_ids)
```

Output:

```
['22614089', '22622854', '22616496', '22601480', '22611197', '22600498', '22605808', '22602601', '22602543', '22594071', '22595982', '22593725', '22591441', '22553315', '22584758', '22582155', '22585128', '22585477', '22587617']
```

Comment: thank you for answering, all of these ids are not videoid, I want specifically video id's, is it possible to get from this tag <a class="icon-font-before icon-chain-solid-before" href="http://www.espncricinfo.com/video/clip?id=22615485" </a>

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; I've changed the solution. Please have a look at it and let me know if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: No problem, Yes this is what I was looking for, is it possible to get one id seperately not in a single list? like ['22614089'], I want to embed this data_ids  to iframe <iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.espncricinfo.com/core/video/iframe?id=22622854&endcard=false" allowfullscreen frameborder="0"></iframe>, So frame id is assigned for each data_ids

Comment: You can use `find()` instead of `find_all()` to get the first id. But I don't understand what you really mean. Do you want a list of lists? If so, just place the `x...[1]` inside one more brackets like `[x...[1]]`. And you can always iterate over that list to use the id's individually.

Comment: {% for i in data_ids %}
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.espncricinfo.com/core/video/iframe?id={{%data_ids[0]%}}=false" allowfullscreen frameborder="0"></iframe>
{% endfor %}
here data_ids[0] is only for first element, how can I do it for all elements?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, but I'm guessing using a loop would help.

Comment: Okie, I'll figure it out thank you for all the answer